# CSS gradients, background image disappear on hover

Tags: css

The facebook logo at the top nov disappears on the hover. I have css gradients applied, no images except the fb logo itself. Is there a way for the logo to remain visible on the hover state?

[css file here](http://www.hauppauge.com/css/nav-sprite-styles.css)

Thanks!

[page here](http://www.hauppauge.com/index.htm)

Comment: Please set up a smaller test case (with as little code as possible, just enough to illustrate the problem) on a site like http://jsfiddle.net or http://cssdesk.com

Comment: sorry I forgot to post the link to the page:
http://www.hauppauge.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could separate the icon from the background. That is, use CSS to place the icon before your "facebook" text, so that it's completely independent from background selectors. Like this:

```
li.facebook a::before {

content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
width: 16px; /* Width of your FB icon */
height: 16px; /* Height of your FB icon */
margin-top: -9px;
background-image: url("path_to_your_FB_icon.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worth noting, though, that IE 7 and lower will _not_ support pseudo-elements :before or :after.

http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

Comment: thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of this. So much easier. I will not the older IE support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple backgrounds, because on hover the facebook background is overwritten by the gradient.

```
ul#topnav li.facebook a:hover {
background-image: url("../pics/facebook-icon.png"),
            linear-gradient(center top , #444444 0%, #A1A1A1 6%, #575757 100%);
/* facebook icon is on top of a linear gradient */
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
background-position: 8px 2px, 0 0;
}
```

Of course you need to add this rule for all vendor prefixes. (`-moz-`, `-webkit-`, ...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Your code and mine look different, I added to the css like this but now I lost the gradient and the image is moving.

Comment: You still need the `background-position`s and `-repeat`s. That is also supported for multiple backgrounds, but it is very hard to find out how this can be combined with your current code, because your css file is really big, and your html file really complex. It would really help if you would make a jsfiddle with a simplified example.

Comment: Also, make sure that you removed your old style declaration for `ul#topnav li.facebook a:hover`.